# How to change Debian NIS domainname permanently? Or, where is the domainname stored?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, hostname, domain-name

On a Debian system, `hostname` returns the *unqualified* hostname of the system, whilst `domainname` returns the (LAN) domain name. For example:

```
$ hostname
nas
$ domainname
lan
```

I know the hostname is stored in `/etc/hostname`. That's fine. So I can change it temporarily by calling `hostname othernas`, or permanently by editing `/etc/hostname`.

But how do I change the domain name? I can do it temporarily by calling `domainname otherlan`, but how to change it permanently?

All my attempts to google the problem have pointed to `/etc/hostname`, `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/networks` and `/etc/network/interfaces`; but I have checked all of those and found no reference to `lan`. My googling also turned up the `libc.so` calls `getdomainname` and `uname`, but again these don't tell me where the information is actually stored on disk.

Other answers on this - and other - forums state that `/etc/hostname` should contain the fully-qualified host name, and the domain name is pulled from that. ***This is not true!*** If I put a fully-qualified host name in `/etc/hostname`, I end up with a hostname of `nas.lan` and a domain name of **nothing** - which causes no end of problems.

Answer (score 1):

The forums are correct; the **DNS domain** name is taken from the hostname if present (although I find that things work better if it's inferred via /etc/hosts instead). There is no explicit setting for it.
*(I have tried [writing down my guessed rules](https://gist.github.com/grawity/cf5a9869a6b128aabfd6) for how Linux determines it.)*

- If `hostname` reports a bare name, then `hostname -f` seems to first use /etc/hosts to resolve it, then try qualifying it with every domain in /etc/resolv.conf until it finds a FQDN that exists in DNS. Thus both `/etc/hosts` and DNS+`/etc/resolv.conf` are alternative ways of setting the "DNS domain name". For example, the following hosts entry (as well as one for `::1`):

  ```
  127.0.0.1  nas.lan  nas  localhost
  ```

  would result in `hostname -f` reporting "nas.lan".

---

However, the **NIS domain** name is not related to any of that. It is *not* the LAN domain name. It is not used together with the hostname in any way or form. It is only read by NIS/YP client software (ypbind) to determine which server to attach to, in case there are several.

The most direct way of setting the NIS domain would be via the **`kernel.domainname`** sysctl, usually in `/etc/sysctl.conf` or `/etc/sysctl.d/99-local.conf`. Unlike for the hostname (which also has a similar sysctl), after searching the Debian init scripts it seems there is no dedicated file in /etc for it.

Comment: But if I put the FQDN in `etc/hostname`, I (sometimes) can't ping the machine by name, unless I substitute "local" for the domain when pinging. For example, "ping nas.local" instead of "ping nas.lan". Wtf!?

Comment: @SodAlmighty: Then _don't_ put the FQDN in `/etc/hostname`. There are other methods. For example, special `/etc/hosts` entries. (Follow the [link](https://gist.github.com/grawity/cf5a9869a6b128aabfd6) for examples.)

Comment: @SodAlmighty: As for the name resolution in LAN: the `.local` domain is handled automagically by mDNS (usually avahi-daemon or Bonjour), but the `.lan` domain is maintained by your router's internal DNS resolver/proxy. When your PC sends a DHCP request to the router, it includes its own hostname as a DHCP option, and the router records it in the internal DNS. So if it occassionally doesn't work, you should try tools like Wireshark to check whether the hostname is being _sent_ via DHCP at all, and/or find the router's "online hosts" list to check if it knows about you. It's not 100% reliable.